# How to use object identifier from c++ header file in python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a binary file, the structure of which is described by header file. I need to parse file in python.
I have the following header file in C++:

```cpp
...
#define DWORD unsigned int
...
// What is the purpose of this?:
#define MGTSIGNATURE    0x54474D

struct MGTMeasureHeader
{
    // Can this be related to MGTSIGNATURE?
    DWORD           Signature:24; // Signature MGTSIGNATURE
    ...
}
```

In python I created the following:

```py
import ctypes

class MGTMeasureHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    
    _fields_ = [
        ("Signature", ctypes.c_uint, 24),
        ...
    ]
```

Now i read file via:

```py
with open('binaryfile', 'rb') as f:
    mgtmeasureheader = MGTMeasureHeader()
    f.readinto(mgtmeasureheader)
```

I do not understand how to use the information from the row in header file:

```cpp
#define MGTSIGNATURE    0x54474D
```

What does it mean and how can I use it in my python code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your include files looks more C-ish than modern C++... Anyway, in C or C++ languages, `#define` can be used to define constant values.

That means that you can simply declare it that way in your Python code:

```
import ctypes

MGTSIGNATURE = 0x54474D

class MGTMeasureHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    ...
```

Comment: in the comments to the c code (which is not mine) it is written (I updated the code snippet in my question as well):

```c
struct MGTMeasureHeader
{
   ...
    DWORD           Signature:24;               // signature MGTSIGNATURE
 ....
```

What could that mean? Could MGTSIGNATURE and the field Signature be somehow related?

Comment: 0x54474D uses 3 bytes or 24 bits. Does it mean that the field `Signature` is expected to have that value in a correct `MGTMeasureHeader`? **I** cannot know that, but maybe it is written somewhere in the documentation for the binary file...